# Are the words act and fact cognates?

Tags: etymology

According to Google, fact comes from Latin factum, which comes from facere, while act comes from agere  via actual. But I remember reading something that said that they come from the same word, and a Romanian native speaker tonight told me the same thing.

Are the words etymologically related?

Comment: What answer (or level of evidence) are you looking for? "Google" here is *probably* NOAD or ODE, from Oxford, which are much more reliable than any non-expert, no matter what language they speak.

Comment: Interesting. Well, sometimes if things are traced back just a bit slightly further, they do still share a common root before they diverged, and so superficial answers while easier to find than very in depth ones, can nonetheless be misleading.

Comment: @Laurel I've lost track of what usually turns up first  in a dictionary search on Google (though it usually looks sound and helpful). They mix NOAD and ODE now?

Comment: Etymology strands before words appear in the English lexicon are not on-topic for ELU, Tyler.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth By default, which you see depends on where you geolocate to; in most cases the only difference between the two is the pronunciation given. See my [meta answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15417/191178) for more details.

Comment: This seems a question on Latin etymology and therefore belongs on Latin SE.

Answer (score 3):

No, **act** and **fact** are not cognates.

What you pulled is what the Oxford English Dictionary shows for the two words:

- *Fact* comes from the past participle form of *facere*, Latin for *make, do* ([OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/fact_n?tab=etymology#4938197))
- *Act* comes from the past participle form of *agere*, Latin for *do, act* ([OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/act_n?tab=etymology#20765021))

So that looks similar semantically and in the resulting form, but *facere* and *agere* are different verbs. Tracing them further back results in different roots:

- *facere* goes ultimately back to Proto-Indo-European root **dʰeh₁*, which means *do*, or *put* or *place* ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/d%CA%B0eh%E2%82%81-))
- *agere* goes ultimately back to PIE root *h₂éǵeti*, which means *to be driving*. (This is indeed the earliest sense of the verb in Latin, and the [Lewis and Short dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dago) lists the driving sense first.)

So no, they are not cognates. They just happen to look or sound more similar in English (and in their past participles in Latin).

Comment: So a fact is an idea that was made, while an act is something you do.